# How can I make the rowediting plugin in extjs to not add a row when I hit cancel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-grid, roweditor

Currently the `rowediting` plugin gives the option of `update/cancel`. When I hit the `cancel` button if it is a newly added row, I would like it to not add the new row.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthradix/gBJ7F/1/)**.

Currently, with the `rowediting`, I am just adding and removing the rows. If it is not possible using `cancel`, how can I add a new button `close` and make it not add the row.

I was also looking at sencha forums and I found a [POST](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131482-Ext.ux.RowEditing-add-some-usefull-features) where it says the following:

1. fireEvent `canceledit`
2. when `autoRecoverOnCancel` is true, if record is phantom then remove it

But, that didn't work, either. Could you suggest?

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,

});

tbar: [{
    text: 'Add Employee',
    iconCls: 'employee-add',
    handler: function() {
        rowEditing.cancelEdit();

        // Create a model instance
        var r = Ext.create('Employee', {
            name: 'New Guy',
            email: 'new@sencha-test.com',
            start: new Date(),
            salary: 50000,
            active: true
        });

        store.insert(0, r);
        rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
    }
}, {
    itemId: 'removeEmployee',
    text: 'Remove Employee',
    iconCls: 'employee-remove',
    handler: function() {
        var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
        rowEditing.cancelEdit();
        store.remove(sm.getSelection());
        if (store.getCount() > 0) {
            sm.select(0);
        }
    },
    disabled: true
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can see how to cancel the non-saved records:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    //autoCancel: false,
    listeners:{
        'canceledit': function(rowEditing, context) {
            // Canceling editing of a locally added, unsaved record: remove it
            if (context.record.phantom) {
                context.store.remove(context.record);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Your fiddle example doesn't work, because you are using there ExtJS 4.0.0. Here you can find a working one with ExtJS 4.2.0: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBJ7F/3/)

Comment: I am sorry, I accepted the answer, but, I found a bug.
I went to the fiddle, clicked on add employee, clicked on update, then, I double clicked it to update again using roweditor, clicked on cancel, the row gets deleted.

Comment: You don't have ID's in your Model. You need to define unique idProperty - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Property-cfg-idProperty But this is completely another problem.